# Wait with executing ko.computed until applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

Say you have a view model with a circular dependency. I know you should avoid this in normal circumstances, but for this case assume you can't because it's out your control.
A parent and a child refer to each other. Below is for brevity a very simplified example:

Html:

```
<div id="root">
    <div data-bind="text: parent.childName()"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var page = {};

page.parent = 
{ 
    name: ko.observable('parent'), 
    childName: ko.computed(function() { return page.child.name(); })
};
page.child = 
{ 
    name: ko.observable('child'), 
    parentName: ko.computed(function() { return page.parent.name(); })
};

ko.applyBindings(page, document.getElementById('root') );
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds6okdkd/5/)

The problem is that `ko.computed` is executed the first time it is initialized. If it would only execute at the moment of `applyBindings` everything would be perfectly fine.

One solution would be to remove ko.computed altogether and just use a plain normal function. Those are only executed at the moment of applyBindings. Problem is of course that you lose all the other advantages of ko.computed, like losing the caching functionality etc.

Is there a way to say that a computed observable only starts initializing at the `applyBindings` phase?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`deferEvaluation`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html) option to postpone the computed evaluation to when it's first accessed:

```
ko.computed({
    read: function() { return page.parent.name(); },
    deferEvaluation: true
});
```

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/dn1n2v6n/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
childName: ko.computed(function() { return page.child && page.child.name(); }).
```

It will return `undefined` if child not set;

Comment: ok, wrong example apparently :) there should be an observable in there. I've updated the answer. Sorry!

Comment: The problem is that the reavulation will not be triggered, because page.child is not an observable. See http://jsfiddle.net/dn1n2v6n/4/